# How to upload files to a folder using a specific user group login and password?

Tags: vba, folder-permissions

I am trying to develop an Access database that allows users to upload files to a folder on a shared drive. I have the code for doing this. However, I would like to not have anyone delete or edit files. For this, I have a folder with write permissions allowed only for one user group. Is there a way that I can upload a file using the login and password for the user group? This will ensure that the files are not edited by anyone else. Please share the code for doing this.
Thank you kindly!

Comment: Sounds like a WIndows share - just add the users to the user group. They login with their own username and password to the network - the share permissions takes care of the rest. Or do you have a database login??? You need to supply code - we don't write it for you

Comment: Thank you dbmitch. For my purpose, I want the user to have a read only access for the file EXCEPT for when they are uploading the file. This is for for data integrity reasons. Their login credentials should only have a read only access to the folder, and from the database, I allow them to upload a file to the folder by programmatically entering the required login for the folder. I do not have any code for this part. Thank you kindly for any pointers.

Comment: I have no idea what you're proposing

Comment: Let me rephrase my request- is there a way to open a folder or a file by specifying login credentials in the code?

Comment: You need to clarify in your question - what login credentials are you talking about? Windows file share? Or some hybrid type of Access login you're using. Your question isn't detailed enough for anyone to figure out

Comment: I apologize. If the folder permission is set for my login to access files in the folder as read-only, is there a way to open the files or add a new file to the folder using a different login credentials through access database? Basically, I want to give the ability to the user to upload files through the database, but they should not be able to delete, move or edit the files afterwards. Let me know if this clarified. Thank you kindly!

Comment: Sorry - out of my element. But if I understand correctly it sounds like you're trying to create ACLs on the fly with VBA. Try this one - maybe it will get you started. Just a note that SO is here to look at problems with code not look at ideas, code writing or ways to do things. Come with your code and errors. https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/231961/changing-the-acl-on-a-folder-through-wscript-shell-within-vba